# Guzzle POST returning GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException Client error: `POST

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Good Afternoon Everyone;

Been trying to solve this problem for few days and as usual this is the last resort after trying to look for a solution from someone who had a similar error.

I am trying to post to an API via xml and having the below error

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException
Client error: `POST https://go.paytraq.com/api/shipper?APIToken=xxxxxxx&APIKey=xxxx` resulted in 
a `400 Bad Request` response: <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>PayTraq - Cloud-based 
Business Suite - Manage your business online</ti (truncated...)
```

As the error is truncated tried to find the best method to get the full error without success .

Please find below my code ..

```
$array = [
        'ShipperName'=>[
            '_value'=>$shipper_name
        ],
            'ShipperVehicle'=>[
                '_value'=>$shipper_vehicle
            ],
            'ShipperDriver'=>[
                '_value'=>$shipper_driver
            ],
            'ShipperRegNumber'=>[
                '_value'=>$shipper_reg
            ],
            'IsDefault'=>[],
            'IsInactive'=>[]
        ];
        $xmlarray = ArrayToXml::convert($array,'Shipper');

try {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri'=>'https://go.paytraq.com']);
        $detail = $client->request(
            'POST',
            '/api/shipper',

            ['debug'=>'false',/*'debug'=>'false',this is debug line*/
                'query'=>[
                    'APIToken'=>'xxx',
                    'APIKey'=>'xxxxxx'
                ],
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'text/xml;',
                ],
                ['body' => $xmlarray]

            ]);

            $response = $client->post($detail);

        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException  $e) {
            var_dump($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());

        }


        return redirect()->back();
```

Below is what you get with echo $xmlarray

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Shipper>
<ShipperName>
test
</ShipperName>
<ShipperVehicle>
test
</ShipperVehicle>
<ShipperDriver>
test
</ShipperDriver>
<ShipperRegNumber>
test
</ShipperRegNumber>
<IsDefault/>
<IsInactive/>
</Shipper>
```

Guzzle debug is below

```
* Trying 52.16.7.7:443... * Connected to go.paytraq.com (52.16.7.7) port 443 (#0) * ALPN, 
offering http/1.1 * successfully set certificate verify locations: * CAfile: 
/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem CApath: /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs * SSL connection 
using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 * ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol * Server 
certificate: * subject: CN=go.paytraq.com * start date: Oct 14 00:00:00 2019 GMT * expire date: 
Nov 14 12:00:00 2020 GMT * subjectAltName: host "go.paytraq.com" matched cert's "go.paytraq.com" 
* issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon * SSL certificate verify ok. > POST 
/api/shipper?APIToken=xxxx&APIKey=xxxxx HTTP/1.1 Host: go.paytraq.com Content-Length: 0 User-
Agent: GuzzleHttp/7 Content-Type: text/xml; * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse < HTTP/1.1 
400 Bad Request < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 < Date: Sun, 23 Aug 2020 14:26:09 GMT < 
Request-Time: 3 < Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) < Content-Length: 3835 < Connection: keep-alive < 
* Connection #0 to host go.paytraq.com left intact
```

From the site this is what is required

```
The transmission of all API requests and responses needs to be made over HTTPS. 
There are two type of requests: GET and POST. GET requests are usually used to read the data, POST request are used to add and update the data. 
All POST requests should be made in XML format with "Content-Type: text/xml" header. 
All success responses are also given in XML format.

400 Bad Request The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax, invalid values or validation issues.

<Shipper>
   <ShipperName></ShipperName>
   <ShipperRegNumber></ShipperRegNumber>
   <ShipperVehicle></ShipperVehicle>
   <ShipperDriver></ShipperDriver>
   <IsDefault></IsDefault>
   <IsInactive></IsInactive>
</Shipper>
   
Only <ShipperName> is required.
```

Thanks everyone in advance

Sarky

Comment: According to the documentation, booleans such as `<IsDefault></IsDefault>` should contain either `true` or `false` and you are passing an empty string

Comment: @ChrisHaas Agreed, but at the bottom it says only ShipperName is required.. but nevertheless i tried it out and same exact error.

Comment: Your xml syntax doesnt match the example they give...

Comment: @miknik do you mean the ShipperRegNumber should be before, tried that still same error. if you spotted another discrepancy please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally got it working

Thats the modification I had to do to get it to work.

Might help someone in the future.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' =>'https://go.paytraq.com']);
        $detail = $client->post(

            '/api/shipper',

            [/*'debug'=>'false',this is debug line*/
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'text/xml',

                ],
                'body' => $xmlarray,

                    'query'=>[
                        'APIToken'=>'3GUoyOxsCznhyiFQ',
                        'APIKey'=>'6421f7ad-418b-46b0-891b-e4385071a88f-7608'
                    ],

            ]);

        $response = $detail->getStatusCode();
```